# Get an Entity Framework 6 Code First Attribute table and column value of a class in C# code

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF attribute values to map to the SQL table and column names that is enforced on me.

I am also required  to set some default column values in SQL.

In **EF 6** Code First OnModelCreating doesn't support setting the **SQL Server** column default value when creating the database.

However one can do it through code first migrations.

Here is an example where I set the SQL Server default value to true for a **Boolean** field.

My entity's class

```
[Table("Given_TableName_1")]
public class Vehicle
{
    [Key,Column("Given_TableColumn_1")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Given_TableColumn_4")]
    public bool IsManual { get; set; }
}
```

DB Migration class

```
public partial class DefaultValueMigrations : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {

          AlterColumn("Given_TableName_1", "Given_TableColumn_4", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));

    }
}
```

I don't want to refer to the SQL table names in code.
The above is also not strongly typed and one can easily make a mistake typing using string fields.

Is there a way to reference the entity class name and the property name  instead.

something like

```
  AlterColumn(GetClassAttribute(Vehicle,"Table"), GetClassPropertyAttribute(Vehicle.IsManual,"Column"), c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));
```

Comment: What if, in a history of migrations, you alter the mapping of a table or column? Migration code is *supposed* to contain hard-coded database object names, i.e. the names at that specific stage of the database.

Comment: Migrations should automatically pick up the table names from the data annotations